# IGBT failure on Inverters

Tags: inverter, igbt

We were using Mitsubishi IGBT with the code [CM400DY-24NF](https://www.mitsubishielectric-mesh.com/products/pdf/CM400DY-24NF_n.pdf) but had to change to Fuji IGBT [2MBI450U4E-120](http://datasheet.octopart.com/2MBI450U4E-120-Fuji-datasheet-15131844.pdf).

These IGBTs are used in inverters and the inverters are used in solar energy applications and connected to solar panels. After this change our inverters started to cause problems at voltage levels like 920 Vdc (solar panels output voltage at open circuit) although their maximum voltage is 1200Vdc. By problem, I mean that they explode just after we connect to the load (solar panels).

What could be the reason of it? 
Thanks.

Comment: No schematic, no part links,....

Comment: 920 Vdc bus for 1200 V rated IGBTs, that sounds like a recepie for disaster.

Comment: [Mitsubishi IGBT datasheet](https://www.mitsubishielectric-mesh.com/products/pdf/CM400DY-24NF_n.pdf)

Comment: [Fuji IGBT datasheet](https://www.galco.com/techdoc/fuji/2mbi450u4e-120_dat.pdf)

Comment: New ones are significantly slower.

Comment: Can this cause the IGBT damage?

Comment: Depends on how you are using it....

Comment: Do they have snubbers? Faster turn off could cause more overshoot.

Comment: If you are driving t too fast it will turn into a linear regulator, and will get very hot, very fast.

Comment: Also, since they are half bridges, if you did not adjust your dead time, you may be shooting through.... which should make a nice little bang at 920V...

Comment: So, conluding on what @Trevor and winny said: voting to close as unclear, since impossible to answer without schematics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, I am not able to provide the schematic.

Comment: Can you tell what brand of solar inverters? I want to make sure to avoid them

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that the t(risetime) is much too slow on the new device. 
The Powerex part is 160 ns maximum, so in all probability you get parts with Tr of perhaps less than half that.... 50-60 ns.
The Fuji part is up to 600 ns maximum, so you likely are seeing parts with Tr around 200 ns.

This would potentially exceed the SOA (though it's poorly defined in both devices) which is normally the reason the blue light escapes.

Do you have snubbers in your circuit; that might potentially save you?

Comment: +1 and that is assuming he "fixed" the rest of the design to accommodate the change, which I highly doubt.